# Error building drivers for QT using MYSQL server (mingw32-make)

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

Today, I want to ask you a question about building drivers. I have my little QT Database like this:

```
mainDB = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
mainDB.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
mainDB.setPort(3306);
mainDB.setDatabaseName("Database_Name");
mainDB.setUserName("root"); //create editors account later
mainDB.setPassword("Password"); //so on :)
if(mainDB.open())
    qDebug() << "mainDB is open";
else
    qDebug() << "mainDB error";
```

However, then I tried to compile this, I received an error:

```
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded             
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QPSQL QPSQL7
```

I googled this thing a little bit, and realised, what I haven't build a driver for QT, using MySQL. So, I typed this at my cmd:

```
C:\Qt\5.6\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql>qmake "INCLUDEPATH += C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\include" "LIBS+=C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\lib\libmysql.lib" mysql.pro
```

(in includepath I used path to all includes in MySQL server (like, a hundred of h. files), and in LIBS I used path to my libmysql file). It compiled good, and I typed

```
mingw32-make
```

to finish my build. However it catches an error:

```
    In file included from main.cpp:36:0:
    ../../../sql/drivers/mysql/qsql_mysql_p.h:55:19: fatal error: mysql.h: No
   such file or directory
 #include <mysql.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile.Release:466: recipe for target '.obj/release/main.o' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [.obj/release/main.o] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Qt/5.6/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/
mysql'
makefile:38: recipe for target 'release-all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [release-all] Error 2
```

and, as a result, my C:\Qt\5.6\Src\qtbase\plugins\sqldrivers is empty.

So, I want to know, how to fix it?

And, yeah, I did include C:\Qt\5.6\mingw49_32\bin;C:\Qt\Tools\mingw492_32\bin; dirs in system as a "PATH" variable.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're running on Windows, you have to install the [MySQL C client](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/) (that's where the `mysql.h` file is coming from).

Comment: Well, i am using it, i have installed all aviable options (includind connectors/workbenches/e.t.c). Problem is - i DO see the mysql.h file in MySQL Server 5.7\include dirrectory - however, mingw don't...or i just don't understand you and you talking about something different?

Comment: Perhaps you're missing the include env var then, see a tuto here: http://www.seppemagiels.com/blog/create-mysql-driver-qt5-windows

Comment: Same error here. Maybe it will be better to download someone else mysql.h file? I don't know why it don't want to bee seen. (Also i will try to change my mysql\qt versions)

Comment: Could you add your .pro please ?

Comment: https://dropmefiles.com/fnSAL

Assuming you want .pro of my project

And, if mysql.pro -> https://dropmefiles.com/6lGcZ

Comment: You .pro looks OK. Are you including `mysql.h` in your cpp file (you should not) ...?

Comment: Nope, all includes are in h (even libraries). I can send my code to you, btw. But i think(mb i am wrong) what the problem is in the uncompiled drivers for mysql - for example. i don't have qsqlmysql, what is a big no-no for working with MySQL in QT. Really don't know, why this header don't want to work =\ maybe i should download one?

Comment: I mean, you should not include mysql.h in your code *at all* (h. or .cpp).

Comment: yeah, i did not.

Maybe i doing this wrong, becuase i did all 
C:\Qt\5.6\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql>qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=%mysql%\include" "LIBS+=%mysql%\lib\libmysql.lib" -o Makefile mysql.pro

in my command prompt, and not in my project, as stated in tutorial you gave me

Comment: The plugins are compiled independantly. You should not have any reference to any MySQL .h files **in your own project**. So no INCLUDEPATH with MySQL is needed.

Comment: I checked again - no MySQL .h reference in my project.

Comment: Where the error `#include <mysql.h>` in the file included line 36 of your main.cpp file comes from then ? That's strange.

Comment: I will check all my .pro files then ( i have, like, tonns of them). Thanks for the tip!

And also code files, yeah

Comment: Hey guys, what happen ?! I am stuck exactly on the same issue (letter by letter)

Comment: @Suda.nese you mean you have an "mysql.h: No such file or directory" error in the build of your own code ?

Comment: @Ilya yes, and can’t fix it so far, any suggestions?

Comment: I Guess that the OP found a #include <mysql.h> in his code (.cpp or .h) because he accepted the answer, but I'm not sure. Did you check that ?